# Cursor interface

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and java. I understand that in the interface, there is no solid implementation code for every method as these methods are all abstract. However, I find that we can use methods in Cursor interface to get specific column number, get indices and many other values. My question is that how it is possible when there is no implementation in these methods in Cursor class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) states:

> Implementations should subclass [AbstractCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html).

A `subclass` of `AbstractCursor` is [SQLiteCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) which implements all the aforementioned methods.

So basically when you use a line like the following to obtain a `Cursor` on an `SQLiteDatabase`

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
```

the `cursor` object you get, is an implementation class of the `Cursor` interface, most probably the `SQLiteCursor` class which has all the required methods implemented.

You can check the real (runtime) class of the `cursor` object, either by debugging or by printing it in the `logcat`, e.g.

```
Log.d("SOME_TAG", "Cursor implementation class is: " + cursor.getClass().getName());
```